# Blur image on UIScrollView swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, blur

I want to blur an image depending on how much a UIScrollView is scrolled. But the part I'm having trouble with is finding a method which can blur an image. I know the class UIVisualEffect but this doesn't seem to work because I can only adjust the opacity and not how much the image should blur at a giving scroll position.
Does anyone know of a method which can be used for this or a lib?

I'm writing the school project in swift.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's possible with UIKit. Using UIVisualEffect you are able to specify only blur type: `.Light, .extraLight, .Dark`. But if you want to specify blur radius you need use third party lib e.g: [FXBlurView](https://github.com/nicklockwood/FXBlurView).

But mind that using FXBlurView is not as efficient as UIVisualEffect.

**Edit:**
If you looking for Swift library, I found [DynamicBlurView](https://github.com/KyoheiG3/DynamicBlurView).
But notice that you have to put your `blurView` above your `imageView`.

Comment: Is there a version of FxBlurView that is written in swift or that can be implemented with swift?

Comment: Thanks this was what I was looking for :)